# handling not found object in repository

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, asp.net-web-api

I have a externall dll in which following is defined

```
namespace MoviesLibrary
{
    public class MovieDataSource
    {
        public MovieDataSource();

        public int Create(MovieData movie);
        public List<MovieData> GetAllData();
        public MovieData GetDataById(int id);
        public void Update(MovieData movie);
    }
}
```

I am calling this dll from repository to perform CRUD in my webapi application,now in my repostory i am writing GetMovieById method in which i am confused what to return if a movie is not found in repository and what is the more appropriate way to handle this in webapi?

**MovieRepository**

```
 public Movie GetMovieById(int movieId)
        {

            MovieData movieData = new MovieDataSource().GetDataById(movieId);
            if (movieData != null)
        {
            return MovieDataToMovieModel(movieData);
        }
        else
        {
            ??
        }
    }
```

***MoviesController***

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a movie
/// </summary>
/// <param name="movie">movieId</param>
/// <returns>Movie</returns>
   public Movie Get(int movieId)
    {
    //try
    //{
        var movie = repository.GetMovieById(movieId);
        if (movie == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return movie;
    //}
    //catch (Exception e)
    //{
    //    if (e is HttpResponseException)
    //    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, you should throw an exception, if entity not found by its primary key.
Depending on use cases, you can put two methods in your repository (and external code, which works with repository):

```
public MovieData GetDataById(int id); // this throws an exception, if not found
public MovieData GetDataByIdOrDefault(int id); // this returns null, if not found
```

and call first one, if the entity *must* present in data source, or the second one, if entity *could* present in data source.

Comment: thnx dennis,but what to write in else section of that method?One more thing then the web api get method, i should not check this (movie == null)?

Comment: It depends on `GetDataById` implementation. I have no idea, how it retrieves data from store. Also, you layers hierarchy looks superfluous, because `MovieDataSource` and `MovieRepository` seems to have the same functionality.

Comment: what type of exception would be appropriate for this?

Comment: @demonicdaron, IMO, this must throw custom `EntityNotFoundException` (or similar). Unfortunately, there's no out-of-box one in modern .NET.